# Top center of garage door bumping opener rail as it closes. Does anyone know the fix for this?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

After 10 years of normal operation, my garage door started bumping the center opener rail just as the last edge of the door passes the very front the rail before it closes.  This causes it to pop back open.  If I apply a slight bit of pull on the door with my hand during this point it will close without hitting.  I figure some bolt got loose or something.  If anyone knows how to troubleshoot this, I would greatly appreciate advice.  Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It might help here if you could include a photo or two that show the door / track interference, the track configuration and the door pull lever configuration. Is the track fully straight or has it drooped/bent down?

Comment: Does a nut or bolt happen to have appeared on the garage floor recently? It might have rolled to an edge. Also, does the door seem to have excessive movement if you try wobbling it a bit, perhaps comparing one side to the other?

Comment: I added some pictures.  I haven't done any adjustments since I got it.  No bolts seem to be missing.  When the door is closed, it seems to be sitting correctly with no gaps.

Comment: After ten years, it would be worth going over all the nuts and bolts with a spanner and making sure they are tight. A [socket wrench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_wrench) would be easier for some of them. Do make sure to use a tool which fits properly as otherwise it could slip and damage the bolt, or cause your hand to be injured. If you put on a thick wool hat, it won't hurt so much when you bang your head against something while doing the ones near the roof.

Answer (score 2):

In your 3rd 4th and 5th picture you see the top roller which is adjustable. Check them on each side of the door to see if the adjustment bolts have become loose. And then as others have said check all the other nuts and bolts to see if any have loosened. If any have make sure it's not adjustable before you tighten it. In fact I see a loose bolt in one of the photos that's probably causing the problem. [image: Loose Bolt on Bracket]

Answer (score 1):

I would check to make sure that the rail has not slipped down a bit where it is fixed against the wall above the door.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but here is my question:
Has the door flexed or Bowed after 10 years of use?
check the door with a straight edge.

Comment: This should actually be a comment since it doesn't answer the OP's question.